# Cant a nextjs client side page use a server rendered component and dynamically pass parameters to it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Page.tsx

```
"use client";

import CardList from "./CardList";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(0);
  function handleClick(offset: number, limit: number) {
    setOffset(offset);
    setLimit(limit);
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <div className="navbar">
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
          onClick={() => handleClick(0, 151)}
        >
          Gen 1
        </button>
      </div>
      <CardList offset={offset} limit={limit}></CardList>
    </main>
  );
}
```

CardList

```
import Card from "./Card";

interface Pokemon {
  name: string;
}
interface Props {
  offset: number;
  limit: number;
}
const CardList = async ({ offset, limit }: Props) => {
  //get pokemon names
  const req = await fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`
  );
  const res = await req.json();
  const pokemonNames = res.results;

  return (
    <div className="CardList grid grid-cols-3 grid-gap4 center place-content-evenly">
      {pokemonNames.map((p: Pokemon) => (
        <Card name={p.name}></Card>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default CardList;
```

Card

```
import Image from "next/image";

interface Props {
  name: string;
}

const Card = async ({ name }: Props) => {
  const rawPokemon = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);
  const pokemon = await rawPokemon.json();
  const sprites = {
    default: pokemon.sprites.front_default,
    shiny: pokemon.sprites.front_shiny,
  };
  return (
    <div className="Card grid place-content-evenly text-center border-solid border-black border-2">
      <Image src={sprites.default} alt={name} width={130} height={130}></Image>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Card;
```

I was expecting my "Gen 1" button to update the parameters passed to CardList so it would display the first 151 pokemon.
I get this error when I press the button:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.

Do I need a separate page for each generation? If I don't, where would I fetch my data for an app like this?
The reason I'm using next and not just react is so I can add users later.

Comment: Have you tried adding `"use server"` on the `CardList`component?

Comment: @grekier Yeah that caused CardList to not render

Comment: Did you get any error in the console then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a structural problem. Fetching in the Card component, which is a part of the CardList component, seems to be causing the issue. I'll refactor the code so that the fetching is done at a higher level and information is passed down through components. Also wrapping the call to Card in CardList in `<Suspense></Suspense>` helped!